# LINQ A simple question

Tags: c#, linq

I have that class:

```
public class Post 
{
    public Oid Id { get; private set; }

    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public Guid Id { get;  set; }
    public DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }
}
```

how in linq select that posts whose comments has e.g TimePosted >= DateTime.Now ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a collection of `Post` objects called "`posts`", you'd do something like this:

```
var result = posts.Where(p => p.Comments.Any(c => c.TimePosted >= DateTime.Now));
```

Note that this is an example of Method syntax. For an example of Query syntax, see [cybernate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358097/linq-a-simple-question/6358126#6358126).

MSDN has a comparison of the two styles available here: [LINQ Query Syntax versus Method Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from p in context.Posts
from c in p.Comments
where c.TimePosted >= DateTime.Now
select p
```